# Is the vortex in a kitchen sink an example of a singularity?

Tags: singularities

Say you have your kitchen sink full of water and you pull the plug. Then a nice little vortex will form where the water disappears into the drain.

My question is:

> Is this an example of a mathematical singularity occurring in real
>   life? And if it is, what is the function of which it is a singularity
>   of?

**Edit**

A singular point of a $C^1$-map $f: M \to N$ where $M$ is a smooth $m$-manifold and $N$ a smooth $n$ manifold is any point $x_0$ where $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: What definition of *mathematical singularity* are you following?

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry I wasn't aware that there were several definitions for singular points. I added the definition.

Comment: Student : make sure you check out the [Falaco soliton](http://www.ussdiscovery.com/FalacoSystem.gif). Unlike your kitchen-sink vortex, this one has no sink. But it does have a "torsion string singularity".

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how you define a singularity.

Wikipedia says:

> In mathematics, a singularity is in general a point at which a given mathematical object is not defined, or a point of an exceptional set where it fails to be well-behaved in some particular way, such as differentiability.

A vortex in the kitchen sink can be described as an irrotational vortex.
A simple example of an irrational vortex is given by the velocity field
$$v(x,y)=\frac{\alpha}{x^2+y^2}\cdot(-y,x).$$
$v(x,y)$ is the velocity of the fluid at a given point $(x,y)$ (we forgot about the 3rd dimension for simplicity).
At the center of the vortex $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the magnitude of the velocity is divergent $|v(0,0)|\rightarrow\infty$. The direction of the velocity is given by the angle
$$\theta(x,y)=\arctan (-y/x),$$
which is not defined in the center of the vortex $x=y=0$.
Therefore, a vortex in a kitchen sink is a singular point in the velocity field of the water, since the velocity diverges and is not differentiable at the center of the vortex.
Actually, it is a topological singularity, since there is no continuous transformation of the velocity field which removes the singular point of an irrotational vortex.

PS: One has to assume that the water is a continuous medium, i.e., one has to forget the fact that water or any other fluid is an ensemble of many microscopical molecules. In fact, at a microscopical level, there cannot be any singularity in a kitchen sink.

Comment: What about the third dimension?

Comment: I think it is not relevant. Just consider $v(x,y,z)=\frac{v_0}{x^2+y^2+z^2}⋅(−y,x,0)$.

Comment: My point is that in the vortex in the sink, there typically is a vertical velocity component.

Comment: Your physical dimensions do not make sense: $v_0$ can't be a velocity - just rewrite your vortex as $\mathbf{v} = v_0 \mathbf{e}_\phi/r$ with $ \mathbf{e}_\phi$ the angular unit vector. So $v_0$ must be something like vortex strength. In addition, the modulus (aka speed) $v=v_0/r$ is divergent, hence indeed *singular*, at $r=0$!

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I think I forgot something in the equation...I will fix that

Comment: No worries - note that the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex) discusses two types of vortices, a non-singular "rigid body" type and a singular one (same as yours), which they call "irrotational".

Comment: @TomHeinzl You probably know this, but it's not just Wikipedia that calls Sintetico's vortex "irrotational": it's pretty universal because the curl of this velocity field vanishes everywhere (aside from at the singularity, where it's undefined). This is the classic $\Omega=\log z$ irrotational, inviscid, incompressible velocity complex potential.

Comment: @TomHeinzl can you check whether dimensions (and other things) do make sense now?

Comment: Looks good to me: $\mathrm{d}_z (i\,\frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi}\,\log z)^* = i\,\Gamma/z^* = i\,\frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi}\,z/|z|^2 = \frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi}\,(-y+i\,x)/(x^2+y^2)$, so your vortex is the velocity complex potential $\Omega = i\,\frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi}\,\log z$, where $\Gamma$ has the dimensions of velocity times length: it is the *circulation* of the vortex.

Comment: I'm happy with the amended answer and the comments by @WetSavannaAnimal. Thanks!